# Random picking 3 chosen numbers

Tags: python

Ok, I am creating a game and no matter what I do, it just isn't working. So I have 3 numbers chosen, 25,50,75.
I want to be able to random pick one of them. Then I will need to be able to add it to a total making it obviously an integer. I have imported random. I have tried random.sample but I can't get that one to be an number that I can add. I tried random.randint and that did not work at all. I have tried looking it up but it is pretty much all random in a range and not specific. Any ideas? Thanks in advance. I am using python 3.4.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice([25,50,75])
25
>>> random.choice([25,50,75])
25
>>> random.choice([25,50,75])
75
```

Comment: Oh ya, how could I forget that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) is the way to go, however, [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) will also work if you use a sample size of 1 *and* you access the first element of the returned list.

```
>>> import random
>>> data = [25, 50, 75]
>>> random.choice(data)
50
>>> random.sample(data, 1)
[75]
>>> random.sample(data, 1)[0]
25
```

The point here is that `random.sample()` returns a *list* because that function is designed to select multiple values from the population. That's why you can not immediately use the result as an integer.

Comment: That makes sense and the way you fix that is by adding that [0] at the end I noticed. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that `[0]` is a subscript into the list... it means the 0th element, ie. the first element in the list.